# Change the title of page according to category id while having an included header

Tags: php, html

I want to change the title of a page depending on what category the user clicked on. So I just stored the info in a variable and called it in a title tag. The problem is that the page with categories also includes `header.php` which calls a different title. How do I overrule that one?

What I got now (on the header page):

```
$titelPagina = $pagina;

<title>Website - <? echo ucfirst($titelPagina) ?></title>
```

On the categorylist page:

```
<title>Website - <? echo ucfirst($haardcr) ?></title>
```

I know this is not a fully functioning code, but I only placed the relevant parts here.

Comment: It looks you are including the `title` tag multiple times, which would be wrong. Is that the case?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Is there a postback when the user clicks on the category and the page loads again or do you perform an AJAX request and the page is updated partially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was some missing code on my side.

I added this to my queries page:

```
$pagina = $haardcr[0]['title'];
```

And called the title in the title tag. Which worked.

I probably declared the title wrong.